# Execute PowerShell Script from C#

Tags: powershell

I need to make an application which will run Power-Shell and run command `Get-Dedupjob`, but I received the following error:

> the term "Get-Dedupjob" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

Although mentioned command works properly when I run this in power-shell (show deduplication jobs).

I suppose that problem could be that program doesn't run command as administrator. 
Is there some solution ho to run this as admin? Or where could be the problem?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {

                  // Get-Dedupjob


                  // create Powershell runspace
                  Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

                  // open it
                  runspace.Open();

                  // create a pipeline and feed it the script text
                  Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                  pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-Dedupjob");


                  // execute the script
                  Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

                  // close the runspace
                  runspace.Close();

                  // convert the script result into a single string
                  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                  foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                  {
                      stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                  }
                  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(stringBuilder);
              }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should import the corresponding psd1 file

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {

                  // Get-Dedupjob


                  // create Powershell runspace
                  Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

                  // open it
                  runspace.Open();

                  PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                  ps.Runspace = rs;
                  ps.AddCommand("Get-Dedupjob");


                  // execute the script
                  Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();



                  // convert the script result into a single string
                  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                  foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                  {
                      stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                  }
                  textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(stringBuilder);

                  // close the runspace
                  runspace.Close();
              }
```

You will need to create powershell object to run the powershell commands. Following are the using statement imports you need to have for the above to work.

```
using System.Management.Automation;           // Windows PowerShell namespace. 
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces; // Windows PowerShell namespace.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I already use these objects:

using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.IO;